# Data arranged in the same column and separated by |

Tags: r

I have a table that is organized as follows

```
id.salario.idade.mun_trab.mun_res.anos_estudo.sexo.meso_trab.semiarido_trab.faixa_escolaridade
1
1|678|49|250375|250375|1|Masculino|Sertão Paraibano|Sim|Analfabeto
2
2|1351.55|36|251030|251030|1|Masculino|Borborema|Sim|Analfabeto
```

How do I read the file correctly or modify the columns of that dataframe?

I tried to format the columns and it didn't work.

Comment: When you read in your file, you need to specify the correct delimiter to split the columns on

Comment: Can you format your example data table correctly. Are the "1" and "2" intended to be on a separate line? If so, what do you intend to do with them?

Comment: Edit the header row, to change the delimiters: `id|salario|idade|...`. Then `df = pandas.read_csv(delimiter="|")`

Comment: Read it in with `|` delimter, skip the header row `header=None`, and specify the `names` parameter: `names='id.salario.idade.mun_trab.mun_res.anos_estudo.sexo.meso_trab.semiarido_trab.faixa_escolaridade'.split('.')` If those blank lines exist like that, clean it up after it's in the datraframe. Plenty of ways to skin this cat.